Filter masstransit consumer events based on metadata/correlationId
I use masstransit 8 + amazon sqs/sns. I have a single Producer that publishes generic event of type EventData. I also have few different consumers that receives this event and every of them executes its own logic.
Consumer1 : IConsumer<EventData>
Consumer2 : IConsumer<EventData>

What I want to do is to filter the event to specific Consumer based on some EventData metadata (probably by CorrelationId field), i.e. to use CorrelationId field to specify which consumer (Consumer1 or Consumer2) can receive and consume this event.
I found the alternative solution that works well using attributes MassTransit Filtering messages a consumer can handle .
However after reading masstransit documentation I think it could be solved by using CorrelationId field as well, but I can't figure out how to implement this approach.
Could you please help ?

Why didn't you just use message types and let MassTransit handle all the routing for you? Seems like you've recreated what's already built into MassTransit.

Hi Chris. In other parts of app we use message types as you suggested. But in this particular case the host app receives generic request from different services (Service1, Service2), processes some background long-time polling (with interval up to 1 hours) and only after that the producer publishes generic event to outgoing queue. The idea is the Consumer1 to receive result of Service1 request polling, Consumer2 to receive result of Service2's request polling and so on, i.e. to have some identifier like "CorrelationId" or "PollingResultReceiver" to filter event to specific consumer.

Huh, I'd just have a consumer for the base type with a switch statement in that case, and have it republish the message with an actual type. Simplify.
